# Custom Tkinter Images

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm trying to create a back button. I have an image called `back-button.png` in the folder `img`.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter as ctk

root = Tk()

ctk.CTkLabel(root, 
  text = 'This is a label', 
  text_font =('Verdana', 17)).pack(side = LEFT, pady = 11)

img = PhotoImage(file="./img/back-button.png")
ctk.CTkButton(root, image = img).pack(side = LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\youtube-audio-downloader\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 11, in <module>
    ctk.CTkButton(root, image = img).pack(side = LEFT)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\customtkinter_button.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\customtkinter_button.py", line 147, in draw
    self.canvas.configure(bg=CTkColorManager.single_color(self.bg_color, self.appearance_mode))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1646, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1636, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "."
```

So, why is this happening? And how can I display an image on a button?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. The error message has to do with a line 147, the contents of which don't exist at all in the code in your question. This is happening because some value returned from `CTkColorManager.single_color()` (which is not in your code; neither are `self.bg_color` or `self.appearance_mode`) is not a valid color. There is lots of code on the site for adding images to buttons; try searching around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the CtkButton widget doesn't not accept parameters the same way as standard widgets. The first parameter to a CtkButton is the background color, but you're passing the root window and the root window isn't a valid color.

You need to explicitly assign the root window to the `master` argument.

```
ctk.CTkButton(master=root, image = img).pack(side = LEFT)
#             ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting error because you are using built-in image define method which is in **Tkinter** not in **Customtkinter**. Don't confuse these two. If you want to use **Customtkinter** only use that because when you are making bigger projects than this, it will be a whole mess if you use these two together.

```
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    
window = customtkinter.CTk()
    
button_image = customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open("assets/yourimage.png"), size=(26, 26))
    
image_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=window, text="Text will be gone if you don't use compound attribute",image=button_image)
image_button.pack()
    
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! The author of the question asked why a specific error is happening, and you only post a bit of code that might resolve their problem. Please add some extra information that really helps the asker + future readers by giving insights into what is going on.